# Special Arithmetic in oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

For example - Column ABC number(12,4).

My value is 2.7487 and if divided by 2 it's 1.3744 (rounding with 4).

```
1.3744 + 1.3744 = 2.7488
```

How do I get a result - 2.7487 as the original.

Comment: Improving the decimal precision: try to round with 8 instead of 4... e.g.: `number(12, 8)`.

Comment: Please show your sql

Comment: @DaltonCézane - we cannot change the datatype due to product support issues.

Comment: @OldProgrammer - I have no sql but this is the concept around the requirement. i tried to round of to 4 digits - but as mentioned in example it does not match to original value.

Comment: This is a simple maths problem, what has this got to do with sql? You need to ask your users what they expect the system to do with rounding errors. The Impaler has given one option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot. That's normal behavior of finite arithmetic (integer and floating point).

Even if you add large number of decimal places, you'll still lose precision.

This is a typical case of the rounding of an invoice. For example you have an invoice for a total of $100.00 that you need to divide in 3 items. You get three items of `$100.00 / 3.0` each one. That is:

- $33.33 Item #1.
- $33.33 Item #2.
- $33.33 Item #3.
- For a total of... $99.99! (not the $100.00 that you expected).

The known solution for ages now is to adjust one or more of the values to add or decrease it by one cent. In this case, you could add 1 cent to the last item, to get:

- $33.33 Item #1.
- $33.33 Item #2.
- $33.34 Item #3.
- For a total of... $100.00! Perfect.

There are multiple possible combinations (all valid) to adjust those values. That's how it's done in accounting.